# How would i be able to access a hidden submodule in QTspim without changing the code?

Tags: mips, qtspim

I need to input a payload that would output the message for the hacked: portion of the code, how would i go about this?

```
   .data
msg0:   .asciiz "WELCOME- first verify your code \n"
msg1:   .asciiz "Give the code(2 or 3 positive integers, and ends with 0) \n"
msg2:   .asciiz "Your Code is : "
msg3:   .asciiz "\nThank you" 
msg4:   .asciiz "\n\n=======> You are hacked <================"
msg5:   .asciiz "\nIf the code is correct enter 1, o/w enter 0):"
msg6:   .asciiz "\nPlease reenter the code later"

    .text
        .globl main

main:
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg0    # argument: string
  syscall         # print the string   
  jal storeCode   # call storeCode()
  li $v0, 10      # to exit the program
  syscall

storeCode:
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg1    # argument: promt for code
  syscall
  addi $sp, $sp, -4
  sw $ra, 0($sp)  # save $ra
  jal readCode
  lw $ra, 0($sp)  # restore $ra
  add $sp, $sp, 4
  move $t1, $v0   # code's address in stack is returned in $v0 
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg2    # argument: printing code
  syscall         # print the string 
loopP:   # do - while ( )
  lw $a0, 0($t1)  # to print integer x (stack), $a0 should contain X 
  li $v0, 1
  syscall
  addi $t1, $t1, 4
  bne $a0, $0, loopP  # do - while ($a0 > 0 ) 
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg5    # argument: printing code
  syscall         # print the string     
  li $v0, 5       # read the option; 1/0
  syscall
  bne $0, $v0, if   # if 1 (correct) is entered go to if
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg6    # argument: string
  syscall         # print the string
  j skipIF  
if:
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg3    # argument: string
  syscall         # print the string
skipIF:
  jr $ra
  
readCode:
  add $s8, $sp, $zero   # $s8 = $30 is $fp in qtspim
  add $sp, $sp, -16
  li $t0, 4      # counter 
  add $t1, $sp, $0  #used as index in stack 
loopR:   # do - while ( )
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  sw $v0, 0($t1)      # storing the read int in stack
  addi $t1, $t1, 4
  addi $t0, $t0, -1   # counter not tested
  bne $v0, $0, loopR  # do - while ($a0 > 0 )
  move $v0, $sp  #code's address to be returned
  move $sp, $s8   # reset old stack ptr
  jr $ra

hacked:
  li $v0, 4       # syscall 4 (print_str)
  la $a0, msg4    # argument: string
  syscall         # print the string
  jr $ra
```

Comment: You have to "break" the stack and change the return address stored there to the address of the `hacked` label which you should look after assembling. I'd try inputting that address five times, then 0 to end.

Comment: Okay so for the return address that I would input would be the hexadecimal value displayed in QTspim correct?

Comment: You probably need to convert the hexadecimal address to its decimal counterpart as i don't think QTspim syscall 5 allow you to enter an hexadecimal value